# Complicated Huffman coding

Tags: coding-theory

I am trying to figure out how to code these symbols. I am pretty sure I have it, but it gets a little tricky. Let A,B, and C have probabilities .71, .16, and .13 respectively. I am trying to code the pairs of them. I use 0 for up and 1 for down. Observe

AA .71^2=.5041

AB .1136

BA .1136

AC .0923

CA .0923

BB .0256

BC .0208

CB .0208

CC .0169

After I have dealt with the lower 4 ones. I get the sum of .0841. Then I add that sum to CA to get .1764. Now I have this

AA .71^2=.5041

AB .1136

BA .1136

AC .0923

** .1764

Now my problem here is that when I add BA to AC since they are the lowest, I get .2059. Then I add AB to .1764 to get .29 to get

AA .5041

.29

.2059

Then add .2059 and .29. Hence I get this as a coding

0 100 110 111 1010 101100 101101 101110 101111

which I might be correct. Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's fine. Since AA has probability more than 1/2 it's encoded by 1 bit to minimize expected codeword length. You have a kind of superincreasing distribution and Kraft's inequality forces the other codeword lengths higher.

Comment: thanks man. I just have never seen that inter looping before and was confused.